# How to block DC signal without affecting the AC?

Tags: dc, signal

ok first of all i want to apologize to U all for bad  and useless info i have provided for U 
simply any body know how submersible pump works it 's a 3-ph motor with a range of 60 HP to 500 HP and 2 KV rated voltage placed 4000 ft under the surface.
sometimes we need to know the temperature and the pressure down there so we put sensors these sensors need 120 V DC to transmit it's data so provide the DC voltage through the down hole cable (-) side will be the armor of the cable and the (+ 120 V) side will be combined 3-phases together at the star point.
there is Echoke console which connect the + 120 V DC with the 3-phases at star point.

at the down hole motor connected in Y so 120 V DC received at the star point also then to the sensors

so need to block the DC signal from getting back to the main busbar
that's all 
here is schematic

[image: schematic to power feeder]

Comment: maybe a simple filter with capacitor?

Comment: 120Amps? Are you sure?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add punctuation and capitalise properly. (1) Please give some context to your application.  (2) What is the AC voltage? Does the 120 A refer to the DC or AC component? (3) What is the source and what is the load? Put all the information **in your question** and not in the comments.

Comment: I'm sure you can find capacitors with low resistance enough at some point that even with 120A it won't heat up too much and still remove your DC component

Comment: thanks a lot guys sorry for my bad English i edited the questions

Comment: 240kW Pump, I don't think you want to get this wrong based on some internet post...

Comment: If this system actually exists can you provide a schematic of how it is connected? There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. What is the 120 V DC signal that is coming back from the motor?

Comment: @romioesr does this system exist? Or is it an idea that you've had? If its the latter then it may be better to describe what you are trying to do. The way to transmit control signals on a high voltage cable is to use a high frequency carrier that can be separated from the 50/60Hz quite easily.

Comment: 1MVA? That's 1e6 Watts! Unless you mistyped, that's a small power plant.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty normal industrial application, with normal industrial parts. Where is this unusual 120 VDC signal coming from? What is it's meaning? If you could explain more about that someone might have a better idea about how to transmit the information that signal represents.

Answer (score 4):

> What I want to know if Ii have AC voltage 2 kV and DC voltage 120 V on the same cable can i block the DC voltage to reach the busbar with a capacitor connected series between the cable and the busbar.

Yes, but let's do some maths.

- You're running 120 A AC.
- You didn't specify the frequency so let's assume 50 Hz.
- Your running at 2 kV. You didn't specify what voltage drop would be tolerable so let's assume 10 %. That's 200 V.
- The impedance of the capacitor will be given by \$ Z = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {200}{120} = 1.67~\Omega \$.
- The relationship between capacitance and impedance is given by \$ Z = \frac {1}{2 \pi f C} \$ so, rearranging we get

$$ C = \frac {1}{2 \pi f Z} = \frac {1}{2 \pi 50 \cdot 1.67 } = 1900~\mu F $$

A quick look around for 4000 V capacitors (for safety) yields these brutes.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 60uF/4000V capacitor. Dimensions: 105 x 170 x 170 mm. Weight: 5.0 kg. Source: [qro-parts](http://qro-parts.com/product_info.php?products_id=96).*

We can calculate the quantity you need:

$$ Q = \frac {1900}{60} = 32 $$

If you were to reduce the allowable voltage drop to 5% you would need double the capacitance or 64 of those big fellows.

---

I have no idea about the quality of these capacitors and they seem small for the voltage and capacity.

---

All of this is an interesting exercise but I suspect that your question has some errors in it and that this would be a very poor solution to the problem you are trying to solve. For a start, we've reduced the voltage to the motor and the voltage drop will change with load. We've also changed the power-factor so the generator might complain. We also haven't dealt with extracting the DC signal or how to avoid destroying the DC transmitter or receiver when there is a 2 kV AC signal with peaks of \$ 2k \sqrt{2} \approx 2.8~kV \$ on the shared line.

I do not recommend this solution.

In any case, it seems most unlikely that your submersible pump is rated at 2 kV, 120 A = 240 kVA and that it is using a single-phase motor.

Comment: actully U were very helpful but why capacitance is so important to take in my calculations 
it 's huge numbers of capacitors 
the voltage tolerance is 10%
and the system is real not exercise 
my company solution for this problem is to but isolating transformer to block the DC component but we are searching for more solutions that cost less money

Comment: the load is three phase motor

Comment: Your question says nothing about three-phase. Many have asked for details on the system but you have not provided them. Why not?

Comment: what difference does it make ??

Comment: @romioesr Is this pump on a VFD?

Comment: @romioesr: "_what difference does it make ??_" Because if it's three-phase you will unbalance the phases. You have come here looking for help. We ask for relevant details that should have been supplied in the original question. You argue with us and refuse. Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Tyler no it 's Schneider breaker protected by sepam M41

Comment: @Transistor why it will unbalance the phases ?
U mean the 120 V DC will be makeing that difference

Comment: @Transistor let's get back to the capacitance , voltage drop is not an issue for me right now all the issue is the DC signal so i think i don't need a high capacitance all i need is a capacitor on each phase and the will get the job done 
am I right ?
sorry for bad info that i 'm providing U with 
thanks alot

Comment: No, we won't get back to the capacitance until you go back through ALL the comments (from others as well) and address all the questions putting the information **in your original post** and not sprinkled throughout the comments. Please capitalise your post and comments properly so they can be clearly understood and so they look intelligent. You are asking us to comment on your solution without giving us enough details of the problem. That's crazy. Draw a schematic of the present configuration and add it into the post.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough context to understand the question. I can't comment due to lack of reputation, so I will put my suggestions here.

You can control DC voltage flow using a diode if you do not want it to go somewhere. You can shield the wire from interference by wrapping the GND around your voltage carrying wire by either twisting wires together or by using a foil coating.

If you are trying to control the A.C. source with the DC signal, use a regular relay or an SSR relay and an opto-isolator. This would protect your DC microcontroller if that's what you're going for.